# How to get Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER in JavaScript using GULP/NODE?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jenkins, gulp

I have a gulp task *getBuildNumber* which uses [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to execute the script.

```
gulp.task('getBuildNumber', function() {
        var buildNumber = child_process.execSync("echo $BUILD_NUMBER").toString().trim();
        console.log(buildNumber);
    });
```

When I run the following command for gulp

```
npm run gulp -- getBuildNumber
```

I always get the output as `$BUILD_NUMBER` and not the actual Jenkins build number.

Can someone please suggest on how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 5):

You can access environment variables with `process.env`.

For example:

```
console.log(process.env.BUILD_NUMBER);
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me.
It only gives all npm details and doesn't give Jenkins details.
So process.env.BUILD_NUMBER is undefined

Comment: @Siddarth If that's the case, your environment variables aren't set correctly. `BUILD_NUMBER` should be set by Jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

Comment: In jenkins, I tried `echo $BUILD_NUMBER` and i get the correct output of build number and and i tried to print `process.env` in gulp task and it doesn't pick jenkins environment variables. Here is my code `gulp.task('version:up', function() {
  console.log(process.env);
  var buildNumber = process.env.BUILD_NUMBER;
  if (buildNumber === undefined) {
   buildNumber = new Date().getTime();
  }
        console.log(buildNumber);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

According to https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback, you need to escape special characters:

```
exec('echo "The \\$HOME variable is $HOME"');
```

In your case, this means you'd need to use

```
[...]child_process.execSync("echo \\$BUILD_NUMBER").toString().trim();[...]
                                  ^^
```